# Stick div to bottom of browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that I would like to stick to the bottom of the browser window (the actual browser window not the page). The div needs to stay at the bottom of the browser window while the user scrolls.

Right now, the div will stick to the bottom of the window on the first initial scroll but it will not re-position each time there is a new scroll. Here is what I have for my jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    var bHeight = $(window).height();
    $('.test').css({
        top: bHeight - 77 + 'px'
    });
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3ecx7zp9/1/

Comment: You should not use jQuery or Javascript for things that CSS can handle on a default basis.

Answer (score 38):

This can simply be done in CSS. Remove all your JavaScript, and do the following:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 77px;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ecx7zp9/2/)

Comment: Wow, that oversight is embarrassing! Thanks for the help haha.

Comment: sometimes we are too engrossed in using advanced techniques that we forget that there is a basic one already..

Comment: This is what I have been using too, but on mobile it acts up while scrolling up and down.

Comment: Using `position: sticky;` might yield a better result depending on the case.

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered using a fixed position div? set `position: fixed` and `bottom: 77px`

However if you must use a jQuery solution change your code to this

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    var bHeight = $(window).height();
    var offset = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.test').css({
        top: bHeight + offset - 77 + 'px'
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3ecx7zp9/6/

That takes into account how far you have scrolled and will set the position of the div accordingly

Answer (score 5):

here you go:

```html
 <div class="test" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 77px; background-color: #333;left:0;bottom:0"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your CSS use `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/3ecx7zp9/4/

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to use `position: fixed;` ?

https://jsfiddle.net/js7tadve/1/

Answer (score 3):

This is precisely what position: fixed was designed for:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uw8f9/

Comment: best solution so far for sticky footer type things on html. width:100% is required for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the below link will work with you.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpgzP/148/)

```
#footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
height: 77px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #333;
}
```